# How to access ListView object from current ListView in DetailView on XAF

Tags: c#, listview, devexpress, xaf

In a DetailView page, I have two ListView. The first one is a GridView which has some information and user can select multiple rows, second ListView is a map that created from IMapsMarker interface. After user selects some rows from first ListView I want to show them on a Map which is second ListView in the same page. So far, I created a ViewController and taking the filtered rows but I could not access the second ListView which is a map. I tried the following code but it didn't work since current ListView is not contain a map.

```
            WebMapsListEditor webMapsListEditor = ((ListView)View).Editor as WebMapsListEditor;
        if (webMapsListEditor != null)
        {
            webMapsListEditor.MapViewer.ClientSideEvents.Customize = SetMarkers(selectedRows);
        }
```

selectedRows is a list that contain Latitude, Longitude and some other properties. So how to access another list view in a current ViewController and set its properties? Or is there a better way to implement this scenario? I'm using Xaf 18.1 version and Web module.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help from your description. For one thing, it's not clear which of the expressAppFramework platforms you are targeting: ASP.NET, Windows Forms or mobile. But also your scenario is quite specific.

The best approach is to contact the DevExpress support center with a small example.